# Bootstrap – Glyphicons without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, glyphicons

I can't get the Glyphicons in Bootstrap to work without JavaScript.
When JavaScript is enabled, everything works fine but when it's disabled, it just shows random symbols. (Try visiting http://getbootstrap.com/components/ with JavaScript disabled)

Is there any way I can use those icons without requiring the user to enable JavaScript?

I've also thought about using Font Awesome, but http://fontawesome.io has the same problem.

**Edit**: Okay, this is weird. It seems to work perfectly fine in Opera, while it doesn't in Firefox.
Do I have to specify an encoding or include the font via @font-face or something?

**Another edit**: The Firefox console shows the following:

```
downloadable font: download not allowed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): content blocked
source: http://localhost/bs/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff bootstrap.min.css

downloadable font: download not allowed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): content blocked
source: http://localhost/bs/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf bootstrap.min.css

downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:4)
source: (end of source list) bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: Those *sites* may require JavaScript, but that doesn't mean that using their icons does. Have you actually tried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misconception / observational error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I wish this was a standard close reason.

Comment: Sorry, that's weird. It works perfectly fine in Opera, even without JavaScript (see my edit above).
Does anyone have an idea why? Do I have to specify a charset? By the way, the icons on both websites (Bootstrap & Font Awesome) are broken in Firefox (without JavaScript) too, it's not just my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font Awesome's icons, don't require JavaScript, as it says [right there on the front page of their site](http://fontawesome.io/). Proof: http://jsbin.com/conerepu/1

Nor do the Glyphicons used by Bootstrap; proof: http://jsbin.com/conerepu/2

Just because their *sites* require JavaScript, that doesn't mean the icons do.

Comment: Thanks for the links... Seems to be a problem with my browser, see my edit in the original post. Sorry for wasting your time :/

Comment: @user1717025: No worries. Using my links above, I see what you mean about Firefox -- I get the same sort of thing at my end. Weird. But their own sites work correctly for me in Firefox with JavaScript disabled, so my links above probably just aren't complete.

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't find any differences in the source codes of the Bootstrap docs and your jsbin. I think I'm just going to leave the icons out for now. Thanks for your help though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it looks like the Firefox add-on "NoScript" caused the problem. After removing it and disabling JavaScript in FF itself, everything works fine.

That wasn't really the answer I was hoping for because a lot of people use NoScript and I don't want to present them with a website full of broken icons, so I'm going to leave the icons out for now. But atleast I know what caused the problem now :/

Comment: If you double-check this (turn NoScript back on and make sure the problem happens, then turn it off again and see it not happen), then this would be the answer to accept (once you can, in a couple of days) rather than mine. But I **really** don't think NoScript is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is a problem with a setting in NoScript which blocks `@font-face` and is enabled by default (Settings → Embeddings → Block `@font-face`).
I'd like to keep your answer as the accepted answer though because it's probably more helpful to people who find this question via Google, as that NoScript problem was an issue on my end.)